# Android-overwrite the Thread?

Tags: android, multithreading

if I have a thread method that called from oncreate method like this :

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
public ArrayList<Integer> num= new ArrayList<Integer>();
public int i=0;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    for ( i=0;i<5; i++)
    {
        threadmethod();
    }
}

public void threadmethod()
{
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Log.w(this.getClass().getName(),"num"+num.get(i));
        }
    }).start();

}
```

I would like to know, how many threads will be created 1 or 5?
Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

5 threads. each time you call the function it will create a new thread. Although maybe some of those threads will finish before the last is created (unlikely, bu possible).